# Debug Code in Black Berry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I want to debug my code in **Black Berry** mobile (8310).
I use Eclipse Editor for writing code.
Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you talking about do you want to debug on real device ???

Comment: If yes you can easily do this see this example on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plHZk1e0X-o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Just select debug as > blackberry device. But your application may need code signing. If so you have to order signing keys from blackberry by filling order form.

Please read the BlackBerry Developer page on [Code Signing Keys](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp) and the [How and When to Sign](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/Testing_and_Deployment_of_Applications@tkb/118/1/How_And_When_To_Sign_V2.pdf) guide from RIM.